# как передать в godot переменную из python-скрипта в godot-скрипт

Tags: python, godot

есть два скрипта - один .gd, второй .py

из .py мне нужны только переменные (строковые, числовые, списки, словари),
их нужно забрать(импортировать) в .gd

каким образом можно это сделать?

пример ScriptPy.py (синглтон)

```
a='Hello' 
b=3
```

пример ScriptGd.gd

```
var t=ScriptPy.a
var i=ScriptPy.b
print(t) #не работает
print(i) #не работает
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Гугл сказал, что годот это разновидность языка си.
Так что есть вариант встраивания питона в годот, но это... не реализуемо...
Следовательно предлагаю просто запись в файл\базу интересующих переменных

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/653390)

Comment: @finally переменная передаётся в файл, откуда берётся иным языком, чем не ответ, если нет реализации прямого взаимодействия между языками? Ну не нравятся файлы исспользуй базы данных, разделяемую память, телепатию.

Comment: спасибо ganz. буду смотреть в эту сторону!